# Dynamic Side Menu generate with PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I still new in PHP programming. I have a config file that store an side menu map array like example below.

```
<?php  
$array = 
[
    'Home' =>  '\index.php',
    'Product' =>
    [
        'Top' => '\product.php?category=top',
        'Dress' => '\product.php?category=dress',
        'More Deeper Example' =>
        [
            'Example 1' => '\example1.php'
            'Example 2' => '\example2.php'
        ]
    ],

];
?>
```

Is posible to convert the array above to the HTML code below? Notice: I must be suport infinite level.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="\index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        Product
        <ul>
            <li><a href="\product.php?category=top">Top</a></li>
            <li><a href="\product.php?category=dress">Dress</a></li>
            <li>
                More Deeper Example
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="\example1.php">Example 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="\example2.php">Example 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use recursive function

Comment: Add your code what you tried, we all are here to give suggestion and solve not for doing your code. :)

Comment: @JYoThI yup I had do some research, the answer is recursive function. But recursive was a bit complicated for me, I currently trying how to code it. Or you have any example for this situation? (sorry for my english)

Comment: I mean example recursive function for this situation, anyway really thank for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$array =
    [
        'Home'    => '\index.php',
        'Product' =>
            [
                'Top'                 => '\product.php?category=top',
                'Dress'               => '\product.php?category=dress',
                'More Deeper Example' =>
                    [
                        'Example 1' => '\example1.php', // note: you missed a comma
                        'Example 2' => '\example2.php',
                    ],
            ],

    ];

function recursiveMenuCreate($menuArray)
{
    $output = "<ul>";
    foreach ($menuArray as $key => $menuItem) {

        if (is_array($menuItem) === true) {
            $output .= "<li>{$key}";
            $output .= recursiveMenuCreate($menuItem);
            $output .= "</li>";
        } else {
            $output .= "<li><a href='{$menuItem}'>{$key}</a></li>";
        }
    }

    return $output . "</ul>";
}
```

The function can go on to infinity(as long as the server can/is allowed to handle)

As you can see the function itself is called inside the function body. That is what makes the function recursive.

**Edit** I put this in the comments, but it might be more clear in the answer itself
A recursive function is nothing more than a function that calls itself. In this case it means that the function will start with the complete array and start with a loop at the first item.

This is `Home`, which is not an array, so the variable `$output` gets a simple list item. The second item is an array, so a new call to the function `recursiveMenuCreate` is made.

As this is a new call, it has a different value for `$output`(currently nothing). It will be filled with the array items of the input array($array['Product'] in this case) and return it to the original call.

The original call will then continue and return the eventual output

Comment: Thank for reply, now I look for it.

Comment: Really thank for it, this is what is want! I try to understand your code. Recursive really make me blur.

Comment: recursive means nothing more than `i call myself`. As php(and other languages) read the code line by line, it will 'stay' on a line until it has been completed.

In this case the function starts at `Home`, puts a list item in `$output`, then goes to `Product`, which it discovers is an array so it does a call to recursiveMenuCreate which will loop though the Product array, then returns its output. That output will be put in the original calls `$output` variable and continues where it left(in this case it will stop and return the output as there is no new array item)

Comment: @Jelmmergu  thank for your patience. I really learn things form you. Now I get some ideas of what recursive is :)

Comment: Do make sure you type correctly though, as an type error is easy to make(jelmergu is with a single M) but can be a headache to dicover your code

Comment: LOL hahaha you make my day x'D. I need to post a new question 'Why jelmmergu not found in comment tags?'

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible and can be implemented easily. But it depends on your database schema. It depends on how you organize and map the categories in your database table. Whenever you render a category on page, you need to check for its sub categories. And if it have subcategories then should create a new list element and display all the subcategories for that category too. And this will go recursively. It is possible but couldn't give you the exact code without knowing your database. Go and give it a try. All the best

Comment: temporary I stored the array in a PHP file called 'sidemenu.php' inside just return the array. But feature maybe will  store the array in database.